# selenium js webdriver - connect to active browser session (A browser previously opened by Selenium)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am using `selenium-webdriver` package to making a bot, every time i run my code, the webdriver starts a new session and open a new chrome window, i don't want it, i want to my selenium connect to currently active session, for example selenium opend a page with `sesssion_id = '5cdfff6e4dfd7e5551795d365db289b2'` i want to get this session to my selenium web driver to connect again to that page.

```js
const { Builder, By, Key, util, Browser, until, WebDriver, Session, Capabilities } = require("selenium-webdriver");

let session = new Session('5cdfff6e4dfd7e5551795d365db289b2', Capabilities.chrome())
this.driver = new WebDriver(session)
```

at the end i want to have sometiong like this:

```js
thenableWebDriverProxy {
  session_: Promise {
    Session {
      id_: 'e3223ea6f94679f8dbb92a6d89780191',
      caps_: [Capabilities]
    }
  },
  executor_: Executor {
    customCommands_: Map(13) {
      'launchApp' => [Object],
      'getNetworkConditions' => [Object],
      'setNetworkConditions' => [Object],
      'deleteNetworkConditions' => [Object],
      'sendDevToolsCommand' => [Object],
      'sendAndGetDevToolsCommand' => [Object],
      'setPermission' => [Object],
      'getCastSinks' => [Object],
      'setCastSinkToUse' => [Object],
      'startDesktopMirroring' => [Object],
      'setCastTabMirroring' => [Object],
      'getCastIssueMessage' => [Object],
      'stopCasting' => [Object]
    },
    log_: Logger {
      name_: 'webdriver.http.Executor',
      level_: null,
      parent_: [Logger],
      handlers_: null
    },
  },
  fileDetector_: null,
  onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
  authenticatorId_: null,
  then: [Function: bound then],
  catch: [Function: bound catch]
}
```

i got this when i log form this:

```js
this.driver = new Builder()
            .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
            .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
            .build()

console.log(this.driver)
```

Comment: the sessionID is created for each dev-mode launch of the browser.  So you need to store that ID when launching in dev-mode the first time, then set it if you are going to attach another driver.  (In the end this creates a bit of a mess though...  what are you trying to accomplish here?)